# TypeError: 'bool' object is not iterable : Google Ananlytics API

Tags: python-2.7, google-api, google-cloud-platform, google-analytics-api, google-api-python-client

I am using the following code snippet to get data from GA in python 2.7:

```
data = service.data().ga().get(
ids = 'ga:########',
start_date='yesterday',
end_date='today',
metrics = 'ga:pageviews',
dimensions = 'ga:pagePath',
filters = 'ga:pageviews'!=0,
start_index='1',
max_results='10000'
).execute()
```

It is giving me the following error:

```
File "pageViews.py", line 129, in main
max_results='10000'
File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/googleapiclient/discovery.py", line 738, in method
for pvalue in pvalues:
TypeError: 'bool' object is not iterable
```

However this error occurs only when i filter the data on the condition that pageviews != 0. When I remove the filter, the code works fine. I am using the same metrics, dimensions, dates, filter, start_index and max_results and getting the results in Query Explorer. I do not understand why I am getting this error and how to fix this. Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
'ga:pageviews'!=0
```

is like doing Astrying != 0 which will result in a false would be my guess.

Try one of the following.  You should be sending a string not a != 0

```
filters = 'ga:pageviews!=0',
```

or

```
filters = 'ga:pageviews!%3D0',
```